# 'Type' issue with NgRx which is not assignable to type 'State'

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have an issue with the 'type' which gives the following error.I have tried changing the type, but still it didn't work.

I have an initial state, which has of three different types.

The todo.reducer belongs to Todo component and I have declared a Main reducer to the entire application.

*Error*:

Type '{ error: string; items: TodoList[]; loading: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'State'.
          Types of property 'error' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Error'.

```
**todo.reducer.ts:**

export interface State{
    items:TodoList[],
    loading:boolean,
    error:Error
}

const initialState:State={
    items:[
        new TodoList(1,'cook'),
        new TodoList(2,'work')
    ],
    loading:false,
    error:undefined

}

export function TodoItem(state=initialState,action:TodoActions.TodoActions){

    switch(action.type){

        case TodoActions.ADD_ITEM:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading:true

            }
        case TodoActions.DELETE_ITEM:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading:true
            }
        case TodoActions.LOADING_LIST:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading:true
            }
        case TodoActions.LOADING_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading:false
            }
        case TodoActions.LOADING_LIST_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading:false
            }
        case TodoActions.ADD_ITEM_SUCCESS:
            return{
                ...state,
                items:[...state.items,action.payload],
                loading:false
            }
        case TodoActions.ADD_ITEM_FAILURE:
            return{
                ...state,
                error:action.payload
            }
        case TodoActions.DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS:
            return{
                ...state,
                items:state.items.filter((items)=>{
                    return items.id!==action.payload
                }),
                loading:false

            }
        case TodoActions.DELETE_ITEM_FAILURE:
            return{
                ...state,
                error:action.payload,
                loading:false
            }
        default:
            return state;

    }



**app.reducer.ts:**

export interface AppState{

    list:fromTodoReducer.State

}

export const appReducer:ActionReducerMap<AppState>={
    list:fromTodoReducer.TodoItem
}
```

Comment: I’d really advice to start using the new create functions in ngrx.. so much easier..

Comment: If you want "error" to be possibly `undefined`, shouldn't it be simply "inform" it to your interface `State`, like this `interface State { //... , error?: Error }`?

Comment: @developer033 Thank you. But the error is going to change,when there is a change in state. Moreover, I have tried changing the values,but it's still the same error.